# static operator () and [] (C++23)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, c++23

[c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) introduced static versions of the [`operator ()`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1169r4.html) and [`operator []`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2589r0.pdf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

struct S
{
    static int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    static int operator[](int a, int b) { return a - b; }
};

int main()
{
    std::print("({})[{}]", S{}(1, 0), S{}[3, 1]); // (1)[2]
//                          ^^         ^^ <-- Create temporary instances of 'S'?!
    std::print("({})[{}]", S()(2, 1), S()[5, 1]); // (3)[4]
//                          ^^         ^^ <-- Create temporary instances of 'S'?!
    return 0;
}
```

It shocked me that in order to call the **static** versions of operators `()` and `[]` an instance of the class is required; I was expecting to be able to call both operators from the type (as other static members) but it is ill formed:

```
//            type --> v        v <-- type
std::print("({})[{}]", S(1, 0), S[3, 1]); // (1)[2]
// static operator() -> \____/   \____/ <- static operator[]
```

But `S(1, 0)` looks like a constructor *haha, silly me!*, it will cause ambiguities if the type `S` happens to have a `S(int, int)` constructor… but what about `S[3, 1]`? This doesn't clash with any in-class entity.

Ok, maybe `type(...)` and `type[...]` are problematic but what about using the scope operator? unfortunatelly this is ill formed as well:

```
//            type --> v          v <-- type
std::print("({})[{}]", S::(1, 0), S::[3, 1]); // (1)[2]
//   static operator() -> \____/     \____/ <- static operator[]
```

---

I've been reading the *p1169r4* and *p2589r0* papers and I wasn't able to find any rationale to "*force*" to instance the type in order to call the static operator `()` or `[]` nor why the `type::(...)` or `type::[...]` forms aren't allowed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What you're suggesting might be an interesting addition, but based on the papers, it looks like much of the motivation is for use with lambdas. With a lambda, an instance is easily available, and the type...much less so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The motivation for static `operator()` and then, for consistency, static `operator[]` was to allow making those operators static. To allow `s(a, b)` to not have to require the extra object parameter and simply hope that it will be optimized out.

But the name of the function is `operator()` - it's not `()`. `S::(a, b)` isn't the way to call that operator today, it's `S::operator()(a, b)`. Allowing this different invocation syntax for operators is a different feature entirely.

The proposals you're citing didn't have rationale to "force" anything because they aren't forcing anything - that's the existing language.

It also doesn't seem like a super motivating feature, since in the cases that you have a static call or static subscript operator, you probably don't have state (otherwise the operators probably wouldn't have been static), so `S::(a, b)` isn't any shorter than `S{}(a, b)`.

But also if you want to use it that way, you could just create a global object of the type:

```cpp
struct S
{
    static int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    static int operator[](int a, int b) { return a - b; }
};

inline S S;
```

Which allows you the syntax you originally wanted:

```cpp
std::print("({})[{}]", S(1, 0), S[3, 1]); // (1)[2]
// static operator() -> \____/   \____/ <- static operator[]
```

Comment: Well, It's obvious that `S::(a, b)` isn't any shorter than `S{}(a, b)` but in the former we're clearly calling something on `S` scope **without** instancing `S` and in the later an instance is created which is weird considering that we're calling a static member. What I mean is that `S::(a, b)` carries a very different meaning than `S{}(a, b)`.